# JavaScript help needed

Tags: javascript

hello i'm using this code for publishing important messages on my applications message wall, i'm using a checkbox for publishing important message on message wall. the problem is that after publishing important message it will again publish the important message without clicking on checkbox, means the checkbox remains true after publishing the important message. please help me for this.
and my code is:

```
<div class="checkbox" id="checkboxShow" name="userCheckList1" style="display:block;" onclick="importantChkBoxChange(userCheckListShow.checked);">

    <input  type="checkbox" name="userCheckList1" id="userCheckListShow" unchecked="unchecked" 
    onchange="importantChkBoxChange(userCheckList.checked);"/>
   </div>

   <div class="checkbox" id="checkboxHide" name="userCheckList1" style="display:none;" onclick="importantChkBoxChange(userCheckListHide.checked);">

    <input  type="checkbox" name="userCheckList1" id="userCheckListHide" unchecked="unchecked" 
    onchange="importantChkBoxChange(userCheckListHide.checked);"/>
   </div>
     <span class="fl"  style="margin:3px 0px 0 0;" ><@spring.message "label.employee.home.Important"/></span>
```

and the script used for this is:

```
function importantChkBoxChange(chkBoxStatus){

        if(chkBoxStatus == true){
            document.forms['messageWallForm'].elements['important'].value="checked";
        }else if(chkBoxStatus == false){
            document.forms['messageWallForm'].elements['important'].value="unchecked";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please start giving your questions descriptive titles. "JavaScript help needed" tells us nothing about the actual problem. Neither do your three questions titled "jQuery issue in IE" and the two titled "javascript error in Mozilla Firefox".

Comment: @Raman: I wanted to help by reformatting and rewriting the question, but it is so badly formulated, I do not even know what to change it to. What are userCheckList, UserChecklistHide and UserCheckListShow ???

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first `unchecked` is not a property of input. You can have `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />` if you want to be XML conscious, or you can simply omit the ="checked": `<input type="checkbox" checked />`, but unchecked is default, so there is no way to us an `unchecked` attribute.

Second, I noticed that there are variables userCheckListHide and userCheckListShow, but I don't see a declaration of those variables. Are you sure that they exist? Was `userCheckListShow = document.getElementById("userCheckListShow")` called after the input was created? Otherwise you're dealing with null values.

Third, with checkboxes and radio buttons, you're not interested in the value, so much as you are interested in whether they are `checked`. You could re-write your function:

```
// changed the variable name so that it wouldn't scroll. Your var. name was fine.
function importantChkBoxChange(stat){
    // since your test is if(checked) set it to checked otherwise set it to 
    // unchecked, you can simply set the checked property directly.
    document.forms['messageWallForm'].elements['important'].checked = stat;
}
```

As a side note, if you want this to reflect whether either of the cb's in your question are selected, then both `onchange` handlers should be:

```
importantChkBoxChange(userCheckList.checked || userCheckListHide.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where to begin , but here are a few pointers .

- A checkbox is not checked/unchecked by changing it's value . It has a checked attribute .Something like document.getElementById('checkBoxId').checked=true
- Use DOM ids to refer to your DOM elements .Ideally .
- if(chkBoxStatus == true) is redundant
- there's no unchecked attribute for checkboxes
- if you want to transmit the checked status of a checkbox to a js function on an event (like onchange) , you can do like onchange="foo(this.checked)"